# A way to submit a file from my server to a website via HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to make something a bit weird. It's basically a Gallery app that runs on a Nodejs server, so that you can manage stuff from your own browser(using localhost or local ip).

There's a website that does reverse image search, and I really would like to add a button in my website that could upload an image file from my website to theirs, and then redirect the user to their website in order to show the results. I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(){
        // What I have tried
        path = '/img/747a758200af581509406dbdd510cef8.jpg';
        fetch(path).then(r=>r.blob()).then(blob=>{
            let filename = path.split('/');
            filename = filename[filename.length-1]
            let file = new File([blob], filename);

            /*
            // Checking if the File works - it does.
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";

            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = filename;
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);*/

            let fileElement = document.querySelector("#file");

            // Doesn't trigger an error, but also doesn't do anything.
            fileElement.files[0] = file;

            // Illegal constructor, can't do this either
            // let fileList = new FileList();
            // fileList[0] = file;
            // fileElement.files = fileList;

            // TypeError: Failed to set the 'files' property on 'HTMLInputElement': The provided value is not of type 'FileList'.
            // fileElement.files = [file];

            document.querySelector("form").submit();

        }).catch(console.error);
    }
</script>
<button onclick="submitForm()">REVERSE SEARCH</button>
<form style="display: none" action="https://theirwebsite.com/search.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="50">
</form>
```

This is as close as I got, and it's what I'm using right now, but it's not what I want to do. I don't want to display HTML in my site, I want to redirect to the image searching website.

```
        let theirSite = 'https://theirsite.com/search.php';
        let theirPath = new URL(theirSite).origin+'/';
        (function submitForm(){
            path = '/img/747a758200af581509406dbdd510cef8.png';
            fetch(path).then(r=>r.blob()).then(blob=>{
                let filename = path.split('/');
                filename = filename[filename.length-1]
                let file = new File([blob], filename);

                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("file", file);
                fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'+theirSite,{
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
                .then(r=>r.text())
                .then(r=> {
                    document.body.innerHTML = r.replace(/((href|src)=('|")(?!https?))/g, '$1'+theirPath);
                }).catch(console.error);


​
            }).catch(console.error);
        })();
```

Any sugestions on what I could do? I looked for hours, but I couldn't find anything interesting.

Another thing, as I said, the server really just is a simple nodejs running in the computer. So, tecnically, I could get a filepath string from Ajax if I really wanted to. But I don't know of any ways to put a filepath string(like 'C:/Users/Desktop/pic.jpg') into a FileList either.